# Get last returned value from Chrome developer tools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console

In some consoles (like python, ruby’s irb, or node) you can access the return value from your last statement with an underscore:

```
> 'Hello'
'Hello'
> _
'Hello'
```

Is there something similar in developer’s tool console for chrome, or firefox?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `$_` to get the last returned result.

```
> 'Hello'
"Hello"
> $_
"Hello"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is that a standard in browsers ? It works on firefox as well.

Comment: @ulysse-bn It seems to be - it also works in Edge and IE.

Comment: **Safari:** works as well, and you can even `$n` were n is the nth command you typed (it is shown at the end of the line)